# FreeType with unicode [ERROR]

Tags: c++, text, unicode, freetype

I init FreeType as following:

```
if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
        printf("couldn't init freetype\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    std::string fontPath = "D:/fonts/newscycle-bold.ttf";
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, fontPath.c_str(), 0, &face)) {
        printf("couldn't open font\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FT_Select_Charmap(face, ft_encoding_unicode);
    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, size);
    g = face->glyph; // declaration like FT_GlyphSlot g;
```

I get glyphs as following:

```
    // load the w_char into the face object
if (FT_Load_Char(face, c, FT_LOAD_RENDER))
    printf("freetype is unable to load char: %c\n", c); // this runs if error was occured
```

And I use `wchar_t*` and `wchar_t` types.

But I see following:
[image]

Comment: What did you expect to see? Could it be inferred from the code you have posted?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with unicode characters and at the end I found that the problem was the conversion from UTF8 string to UTF16 (wstring). I was using `mbstowcs` function to do the conversion, but symbols like '€' are not converted as expected. The way it works ok for me is with the new C++11 `std::wstring_convert` class. Try this:

```
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<wchar_t>, wchar_t> convert;
const std::wstring wideText = convert.from_bytes(_text);
```

Now pass the `wideText` string to FreeType.

Answer (score 1):

I guess for initializing a string with wide chars, you need to initialize them like this:

```
wchar_t c = L'آ';
wchar_t w = _T('آ');
wchar_t *s = L"Hآ文";
wchar_t *q = _T("Hآ文");
```

but if you are loading the string at run-time, you must convert the string to ut16 or utf-32, either by saving the string file as utf-16 or utf-32 file in some text editors or by converting your utf-8 formatted string to utf-16 formatted string with a function.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late, but I had the same issue. The reason is that you are using the wrong function to load the character/glyph.

All you have to do is to replace `FT_Load_Char` by `FT_Load_Glyph`.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be that **your font doesn't have the Glyphs** you try to show.

I had the same problem with japanese chars 'あえいおう' and searched for days - only to find out that my **font did only contain ASCII** character set **and some western sets, but no asian sets**.

If the Glyph is not within the font, it gets replaced by either ...

- ... an empty square (see your screenshot), or ...
- ... a square with a centered 2-lined hexadecimal glyph-id

Example: [Image: rendered 'あえいおう' + 1 errornous glyph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iI6mc.png)

**The font** I used for this example **contains japanese character sets**, but **doesn't contain Thai/Vietnamese sets**, so that's why **japanese chars are shown**, whereas **Thai/Vietnamese chars aren't**.
(Though I don't know why it's sometimes a square with glyph-id, and sometimes without it)

## If you see that square, you'll know that the glyph with the borderd glyph-id simply doesn't exist in your font file. You have to use a unicode font.

For testing purposes you might want to use the Arial Unicode from standard windows fonts.

To get ARIALUNI.TTF (Arial Unicode):

1. Open Start-Menu (`Windows-key`) and type: `font`
2. Open "Show installed fonts"
3. In Fonts window search (`F3`) for `Arial Uni`
4. Look for `Arial Unicode MS Standard`
5. Drag and Drop it e.g. to Desktop (or to any other place)

Use that font for unicode text.